# Django; Will not make the correct request

Tags: python, django, django-templates, request, django-views

I am just beginning to learn how to use django. I have set up my views.py, urls.py, settings.py, and relative HTML pages. I am able to get the index page to come up but not the about page (only outputs some text) or my category page. I am assuming that the problem is affecting them both.

Views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from rango.models import Category
from rango.models import Page

def index(request):
    # Obtain the context from the HTTP request.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('id')[:5]
    context_dict = {'categories': category_list}

    # Render the response and send it back!
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_dict, context)

def about(request):
    # Request the context of the request.
    # The context contains information such as the client's machine details, for example.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    context_dict = {'boldmessage': "I am from the context"}

    return render_to_response('/about.html', context_dict, context)

def category(request, category_name_url):
    # Request our context from the request passed to us.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    category_name = category_name_url.replace('_', ' ')


    context_dict = {'category_name': category_name}

    try:

        category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)

        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)

        # Adds our results list to the template context under name pages.
        context_dict['pages'] = pages

        context_dict['category'] = category
    except Category.DoesNotExist:


        # Go render the response and return it to the client.
    return render_to_response('rango/category.html', context_dict, context)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url   
from rango import views  

# At the top of your urls.py file, add the following line:
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'$', views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'about/$', views.about,name='about')) 
    #url(r'category/$', views.category,name='category'))

# UNDERNEATH your urlpatterns definition, add the following two lines:
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'media/(?P<path>.*)','serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

My template directory has been hard coded so it really shouldn't be a problem

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('C:/Users/aharon/Desktop/TEMP',)
```

Keep in mind that I am very noob so please be easy on me and I would like as much explanation as possible. Thank You!

Comment: What errors are you seeing? For your `about` view, I suspect you do not want the leading `/` in your template name. For `category` I am not as sure, although having no code in your `Category.DoesNotExist` except block is odd.

Comment: Well, I was not seeing any errors until I did what Daniel suggested but its only on the /about page.

Answer (score 1):

You have not anchored your regexes with `^` at the start. Without that, your first pattern will match every single URL. You should makes sure they all start with `^`.

Comment: While I agree that that was one error, it was not the one that was the problem. Now I am trowing an  `utf8 codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte` error